# Spring @GetMapping with @RequestParam and @RequestBody fails with HttpMessageNotReadableException

Tags: spring, http, swagger, spring-restcontroller

Request to the endpoint fails with the following error:

> 400 Bad request
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   Required request body is missing

```
@GetMapping
public List<SomeObject> list(@RequestParam(required = false) String parameter, @RequestBody String body, @RequestHeader("Authorization") String token) {
.....
}
```

if `@GetMapping` would be changed to `@PostMapping` everything works like a charm though. 
Any ideas what the heck is going on ?

**NOTE:** Swagger is used for request sending, so it is quite unlikely that the error is in Curl

**UPDATE:**
So, it looks like Spring does not support `@RequestBody`  for `@GetMapping`. I still can not figure out why ? `@DeleteMapping` with `@RequestBody` works fine and according to HTTP/1.1 GET requests could potentially contain the body - stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

IMO it looks a bit inconsistent to allow body in `DELETE` but forbid in `GET`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`@RequestBody` annotation binds the content sent in (POST / PUT) request body with the annotated variable. Since there is no 'body' part in GET request, spring throws HttpMessageNotReadableException to indicate the same.

As a general rule, you can only use `@RequestBody` for the requests which can have 'body' content e.g. POST or PUT.

Comment: Hmmm.... but GET also can have body - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html  And spring allows to use RequestBody for GetMapping

Comment: Take a look at this line, in the same article -

**Both HTTP GET and HTTP POST can be used to execute search with body. Since not all clients support GET with body, POST is allowed as well.**

GET request with a body is not correct according to HTTP standard.

Comment: So, what is the point - Spring does not support RequestBody for GetMapping ?

Comment: Correct. Now you got it.

Comment: Get request can have body according to HTTP/1.1 see -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Comment: Also, If Spring does not support  RequestBody for GetMapping why there is no compilation error ?

Comment: There is no compilation error because it is syntactically valid Java code.

Comment: Well, it looks like you are right that Spring does not support RequestBody for GetMapping which is weird IMO because DeleteMapping works

Comment: @IlyaBuziuk If you are satisfied with the explanation, please mark this as an answer.

Comment: thank you! I will do it in a couple of days, just want to get some other opinions (if any)

Comment: IMO it is a kind of inconsistent that DeleteMapping is supported (for me it is antonym to GetMapping and semantics should be the same). So, could you please update your question with DeleteMapping info (it is not only PUT / POST as you have mentioned)

Answer (score 1):

I met the similar problem today in spring-webmvc 5.1.5 and checked the library code. The `HttpMessageNotReadableException` was thrown from `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters` since it invoked `readWithMessageConverters` and got null. There is an loop in `readWithMessageConverters` searching suitable converter for the request Content-Type (`for (HttpMessageConverter<?> converter : this.messageConverters)`), and because I didn't specify and Content-Type in request, it failed.

So I specified the header `Content-Type: application/json` and solved the problem.