# HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, get, axios

I have server running on Spring and it has a rest method for `GET`, here is what it looks like:

```
@GetMapping("/user")
    ParentInOut getUsersOnly(@RequestBody ParentInOut clientSide)
    {
        return new ParentInOut(userRepository.findAll());
    }
```

I'm trying to use `axios` in my react.js application to get data:

```
let dumbJSON={
        "messages":"",
        "localDateTime":getValue(parameter)
    };
    const config = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: url,
        body : dumbJSON,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };
    axios(config).then(function (res) {
        console.log(res);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

But it gives me error,saying **Error: Request failed with status code 400** in web-console

And in spring console, I get **Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing:** warning

**How this can be resolved ?**

I have also tried this :

```
var headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };
    axios
        .get(url, dumbJSON, {headers})
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(erro => {
            console.log(erro.response);
        });
```

Gives me same error and warning but this time gets a response, which is the axios object itself with dumbJSON,headers,url etc.

Comment: Can you be more specific? You have Post mapping in java code and are using get mapping in your request from react code?

Comment: @SudipBolakhe, that was a mistake, i corrected it

Comment: Please use post mapping for sending a request body. Or pass the value as the request parameter. Refer to this post and answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42256358/spring-getmapping-with-requestparam-and-requestbody-fails-with-httpmessagenot